# Run Python application on DigitalOcean

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, console, digital-ocean

I need help to start my Python application on **DigitalOcean droplet**. I set up all the settings and now can run my python file. But if I close the Ubuntu console - my loop or any other code (sending requests for example) finish. I want to start a Flask server which will receive webhooks all time when machine works (**24/7**). How can I start the process without working console on my Desktop? The question is not about Flask, only about endless working program. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `screen` or `nohup` to have your python script running 24/7.

`screen` allows you to create a terminal session and detach from it, leaving the process started on it running. You can install it on Ubuntu with the command below. See this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-screen-on-an-ubuntu-cloud-server) or [this one](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/) for more information.

```
sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install screen
```

`nohup` allows you to do the same. It basically runs a command ignoring hangup signals, not stopping when you log out. Unlike `screen`, `nohup` is normally already installed by default on Ubuntu. See its [manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nohup.1.html) for more information about it.

Finally, in case you are interested in knowing more about the differences between `screen`and `nohup`, they were explained in this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24658/nohup-vs-screen).

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful links. As I can see, screen is used more often.